# Trouble with XUL overlay, stringbundleset, getString is not a function, but createBundle method works

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

So I am working on an old XUL overlay add-on and encountered this problem, and simplified it to a minimal add-on.  Was wondering if someone could explain to me if I am doing something wrong, if I misunderstood something, or how to get this to work as expected.  Complete code below.  Testing in both FF 29.0b1 and 49.0a1, same results.

In the main XUL file, I define a stringbundleset and a stringbundle, both with (very likely) unique IDs.  In the JavaScript file, I want to simply get the bundle (not the set) by element ID, and use the getString (or getFormattedString) method.  In the main JavaScript file, I have an event listener call a load function which can call other functions, including an init function, where I put the string grabbing code.  All the string variables are defined globally with var (outside the init function).  The problem is, I get `getString is not a function`.  Further, `console.log()` DOES NOT EVEN WORK ANYWHERE IN THE FUNCTION, so I can't even check the value of variable that's supposed to hold the returned strings bundle.

In my add-on, I use the exact same pattern in Options and About XUL files, and it works, as the MDN documentation says it should.  So I excluded this from the example code.

If attempting to build and test, note that in the example JavaScript code, I have the broken block that tries to use the XUL stringbundle and fails, and the working pure javascript-only technique which uses createBundle() is commented out.  This is easily modified with the `//* code /**/` comment pattern, just delete the 1st `/` and add a `/` on the other block and rebuild the xpi.

Here's an example screenshot of what the working code should create.  The add-on relies on the old status bar.  I used ["The Addon Bar (Restored)"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-addon-bar/) add-on.  Note "TSBS" on the status bar.  Right click "TSBS", a menu pops up with `Options` at the top.  These labels are pulled in from the `.dtd` file.  The `Menu` is a sub menu that has labels set by the `tsbs.js` script, pulling values from the `.properties` file.  The example shows them pulled from the JS-only method.  I am trying to get it to work from the XUL/DOM method.

I realize that XUL add-ons will die soon anyways.  I realize that I shouldn't be relying solely upon the status bar.  I realize I should just use the JS-only method as it seems more reliable.  But I am asking this because I noticed it and wanted to learn from it.  Any idea how to correct or improve the code pattern, or is this a known problem or common pitfall?

[image: example screenshot]

**`Directory tree:`**

```
test_string_bundle_set-1.0.0-fx
  +-- chrome
  |     +-- content
  |     |     +-- tsbs.js
  |     |     +-- tsbs.xul
  |     +-- locale
  |     |     +-- en-US
  |     |           +-- contents.rdf
  |     |           +-- tsbs.dtd
  |     |           +-- tsbs.properties
  +-- chrome.manifest
  +-- install.rdf
```

**`chrome.manifest:`**

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}/content/tsbs.xul

content {00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570} chrome/content/

locale {00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570} en-US chrome/locale/en-US/
```

**`install.rdf:`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}</em:id>
        <em:version>1.0.0</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>

        <em:name>Test String Bundle Sets</em:name>
        <em:description>Test String Bundle Sets</em:description>
        <em:creator>Quite A. Character</em:creator>

        <!--Firefox-->
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>29.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>49.*</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>  
</RDF>
```

**`chrome/content/tsbs.js:`**

```
var tsbs_strings;

var tsbs_string_4;
var tsbs_string_5;
var tsbs_string_6;

function tsbs_load( ) {
    tsbs_init( );
    return true;
}

function tsbs_close( ) {
    return true;
}

window.addEventListener( 'load', tsbs_load, false );
window.addEventListener( 'close', tsbs_close, false );

function tsbs_init( ) {
    //* XUL/DOM method
    tsbs_strings    = document.getElementById( 'tsbs-strings' );

    console.log( 'TSBS->tsbs_init()->tsbs_strings: ' + typeof tsbs_strings );

    tsbs_string_4   = tsbs_strings.getString( 'tsbs.properties.string.4' );
    tsbs_string_5   = tsbs_strings.getString( 'tsbs.properties.string.5' );
    tsbs_string_6   = tsbs_strings.getString( 'tsbs.properties.string.6' );
    /**/
    /* JS-only method
    tsbs_strings    = Services.strings.createBundle( 'chrome://{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}/locale/tsbs.properties' );

    console.log( 'TSBS->tsbs_init()->tsbs_strings: ' + typeof tsbs_strings );

    tsbs_string_4   = tsbs_strings.GetStringFromName( 'tsbs.properties.string.4' );
    tsbs_string_5   = tsbs_strings.GetStringFromName( 'tsbs.properties.string.5' );
    tsbs_string_6   = tsbs_strings.GetStringFromName( 'tsbs.properties.string.6' );
    /**/

    document.getElementById( 'tsbs-item-4' ).label = tsbs_string_4;
    document.getElementById( 'tsbs-item-5' ).label = tsbs_string_5;
    document.getElementById( 'tsbs-item-6' ).label = tsbs_string_6;
}
```

**`chrome/content/tsbs.xul:`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}/locale/tsbs.dtd">

<overlay id="tsbs-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}/content/tsbs.js"/>

    <stringbundleset id="tsbs-stringset">
        <stringbundle id="tsbs-strings" src="chrome://{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}/locale/tsbs.properties"/>
    </stringbundleset>

    <statusbar id="status-bar">
        <statusbarpanel
            id="tsbs-display"
            label="&tsbs.dtd.statusbarpanel.display;"
            pack="end"
            context="tsbs-contextmenu"
        />
    </statusbar>

    <window id="main-window">
        <vbox id="tsbs-notifier">
            <popupset id="mainPopupSet">
                <menupopup id="tsbs-contextmenu" position="before_end">
                    <menuitem id="tsbs-options" label="&tsbs.dtd.options;"/>
                    <menuitem label="&tsbs.dtd.string.1;"/>
                    <menuitem label="&tsbs.dtd.string.2;"/>
                    <menuitem label="&tsbs.dtd.string.3;"/>
                    <menu id="tsbs-menu" label="&tsbs.dtd.menu;">
                        <menupopup id="tsbs-submenu">
                            <menuitem id="tsbs-item-4"/>
                            <menuitem id="tsbs-item-5"/>
                            <menuitem id="tsbs-item-6"/>
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>
                </menupopup>
            </popupset>
        </vbox>
    </window>

</overlay>
```

**`chrome/locale/en-US/contents.rdf:`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:chrome="http://www.mozilla.org/rdf/chrome#">
    <Seq about="urn:mozilla:locale:root">
        <li resource="urn:mozilla:locale:en-US"/>
    </Seq>
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:locale:en-US">
        <chrome:packages>
            <Seq about="urn:mozilla:locale:en-US:packages">
                <li resource="urn:mozilla:locale:en-US:{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}"/>
            </Seq>
        </chrome:packages>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

**`chrome/locale/en-US/tsbs.dtd:`**

```
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.statusbarpanel.display    "TSBS"      >
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.options                   "Options"   >
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.menu                      "Menu"      >
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.string.1                  "One"       >
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.string.2                  "Two"       >
<!ENTITY tsbs.dtd.string.3                  "Three"     >
```

**`chrome/locale/en-US/tsbs.properties:`**

```
extensions.{00735700-7357-7357-7357-073570073570}.description=Test String Bundle Sets
tsbs.properties.string.4=four
tsbs.properties.string.5=five
tsbs.properties.string.6=six
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your problem:

```
<stringbundleset id="tsbs-stringset">
```

In XUL overlays if a direct child of `<overlay>` has an ID, it's supposed to match an element in the base document. [If it does, its contents is inserted under the matching element. If it doesn't this part of an overlay is ignored.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Overlays#Simple_help_menu_stored_in_an_overlay)

The existing stringbundleset in browser.xul [can be matched using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localizing_an_extension):

```
<stringbundleset id="stringbundleset">
```

Also I don't believe there's a 'close' event (use 'unload'), and you don't need the contents.rdf since Firefox 2 or so. Regarding `console.log()` not working - you checked the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), not the Web Console, right?

Comment: Ahh!  I was aware that certain tags had to match overlay, but I was not sure which ones.  It is the inverse logic in JavaScripts, where you try to use unique names to avoid reassignment of existing variables.  But that would be better addressed by wrapping the script in an object.  Anyways, in my haste I must have changed the stringbundleset ID in the overlay XUL.  Thank you for the tip, glad it was simple.  And glad I could get rid of those contents.rdf.  One less thing to maintain.  Thanks also for that tip!  So I can look in `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` to make sure I overlap IDs.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did check the Browser Console, forgot to say that.  Ctrl-Shift-J brings it up for me, with all logging options toggled on (Net + req/resp bodies, CSS, JS, Security, Logging).  I am back here because my main add-on suddenly started doing this again.  Really annoys me.  The XUL is properly set, so the error lies elsewhere.  My demo works, and the real code doesn't, they look exactly the same, and I have no way to log.  Have 4 .js files included with `<script>`, used to be 2-3.  Maybe order is important and they load out of order now?  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Decided using XUL stringbundleset isn't worth the time wasted.  Just handling it all in JS, where I it works as expected, or else I can at least I get an error and can insert console.logs to see what it's doing.

Comment: @user314159 I'd try `alert` or another way to modify the UI. Or maybe even the browser debugger - we have fancy tools now, unlike the old days! I find it really hard to believe that an ignored tag in the overlay (`<stringbundleset id="wrong-id">`) or trying to access an element that doesn't exist (`tsbs_strings    = document.getElementById( 'tsbs-strings' );`) would affect console.log in any way, so it's really strange that you blame this on XUL stringbundleset...

Comment: alert gave an error about trying to use a user interface call without a window or something odd.  I tried opening the debugger, but it only lets me debug the currently opened tab ( about:addons ), I have no idea how to get the debugger to attach itself to the goings-on of an add-on post "onload" but pre "initialized" state.  The problem is in other JS code, but reliance on the bundleset prevented useful error messages which JS threw and led me down the path to fixing it.  Bundles are great when the other code works too.  But not worth the time wasted to switch to pure JS every time I debug.

Comment: Your answer was the correct one, and did help me to correctly use the bundle, and avoid that problem in the future, and bundles are great in that the resulting JS code is a few characters shorter per line.  But I have repeatedly run into this scenario now, where a JS error is thrown regarding a bundleset object when the real error is masked.  I simply got tired of changing everything to pure JS just to troubleshoot, then change it all back, then waste time on subsequent errors.

Comment: @user314159 OK. Note there's a "Browser Debugger" in "Browser Toolbox", which you can use to debug the code in browser.xul scope (when it works...)

Comment: Thank you again, for your suggestion.  I think this makes the 3rd or 4th or 5th "Console" now, in the same browser, each which does different things, and all have the same or similar user interface, while many older or production versions do not have it at all... or they act very differently ... it is maddening, such a lack of consistency, with important tools hidden.  But that tool does let me look at so many variables, etc.  I have been flying blind, and this will help a bit.  The DOM tool still needs work.  Anyways, on to my next question... :)